# Loading Assemblies from Resource C#

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

So I'm trying to keep all dependencies (including unmanaged - so no ILMerge) inside my portable application in C# .NET 2.0.

At first, I successfully wrote the DLLs to disk by using `File.WriteAllBytes("DLLName.dll", Propertes.Resources.dll_name)` so the program could read from these, but the problems were the time taken to write them and the clutter it caused.

Instead, I noticed `Assembly.Load`. This is the code I used to read the dependencies from my resources into the program:

```
try
{
    // Load OpenHardwareMonitorLib
    Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.lib_hardware_monitor);

    // Some computers explicitly require 32 or 64 bit versions of SQLite. Load either version depending on architecture.
    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE") == "AMD64")
    {
        // 64 bit version
        Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.lib_sqlite_x64);
    }
    else
    {
        // 32 bit version
        Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.lib_sqlite_x86);
    }
}
catch ...
```

And that seems to work okay. Well, at least on my computer. It entered the catch block on my friend's PC, but I assume the answers you'll so kindly write will hit both birds with one stone.

However, this is the error I got from my computer after the try/catch when the program enters the main Application:

"Could not load file or assembly 'OpenHardwareMonitorLib, Version=0.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

But of course, it's still looking for the actual DLL files. Now, how do I fix this?

#### Additional Details

OpenHardwareMonitorLib has no external dependencies. I have also updated the question to make clear the fact it's not working on *my* computer *after* the try/catch block, nor my friend's computer which fails *in* the shown try/catch block.

Comment: Do you have all dependencies inside your executable? Does your old executable (saving files) work on your friend's machine?

Comment: @xxbbcc Yes. The executable worked standalone on both our computers when it used write-to-disk method.

Comment: Update: I ended up using a different method whereby I dynamically write the DLL files to the working directory when the program is run, but only if the files need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Assembly.Load(byte[]) overload.  That's a pretty troublesome way to load assemblies in general.  The specific problem you are having here is that you are trying to load a mixed-mode assembly.  SqlLite contains both native and managed code.  The overload you are using only supports pure managed assemblies.

You cannot do it this way.

I would recommend the simple and universal solution to your problem, one that also works on machines that have UAC to stop you from what you're trying to do.  A single executable with the name "setup.exe".

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll look into some other alternatives for loading DLLs; however I doubt the problem I'm facing is entirely down to mixed-mode. OpenHardware isn't, yet that is what I am experiencing difficulties with on my machine. 'Setup' is a cute idea, but not really an option for my strictly portable application.

Comment: That did give me some pause.  A portable app that uses native code?  And a DLL that has "hardware" in its name that doesn't use native code?

Comment: I completely agree.  Computers have a knack for operating the two-by-four to your forehead without holding a grudge.

Comment: So what I need is something more like [DllImport()], but how can I do something like this with raw bytes rather than a string filename?

Answer (score 0):

Culprit is most likely one of the dependencies of the DLL rather than itself. So your code probably is OK but dependencies need to be installed on the machine.

You can use [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to see the errors.

Comment: I don't think either of us have fuslogvw?

Comment: I have it, I do not about you.

Comment: Question clarified: I don't think you realised it doesn't work properly on my computer either.

Answer (score 0):

May be one of the dependent dll missing on your friends computer. Please use Fusion Log Viewer to identify them

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx